# Outlook: remind me of the incomplete tasks that are due today before closing Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, tasks

So I want outlook to remind me about the tasks that are due today and are not marked complete before closing the Outlook application. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but you're going to need to get your hands dirty with VBA. The `Application_Quit` function is called when Outlook exits - so put your VBA to warn about due tasks in there.

Comment: @Richard, Application_Quit won't help in this case because it can't prevent Outlook from exit.

Comment: @thims True, the best you can do is use it to relaunch Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible via Outlook build-in options. It could be possible via some add-ins.

Comment: Can you back this up with an explanation or reference?